# Add a Publish profile will not work in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2022, webapi

My visual studio is the 2022 17.4.3 version. I have created a simple web API project and I need to publish it, but in the publish window, there is nothing and if I press `Add a Publish profile` nothing will happen.

[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you see anything in the Output window?

Comment: @stuartd nothing will show in output window.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

I did not reproduce this issue after trying various settings of the asp.net web api project before publishing. This also just shows that there is an issue in Visual Studio itself during the use of Visual Studio.

**The simplest and most effective solution: reinstall Visual Studio**

However, this approach can cause a lot of inconvenience and result in the loss of many previously customary settings. Please refer to [Synchronize Visual Studio settings across multiple computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). This will make reinstalling Visual Studio less annoying.

If you are very resistant to reinstalling Visual Studio, then you can open Visual Studio Installer=>Individual components=>search for "Connectivity and publishing tools"=>try to uninstall and reinstall it. This is often effective for issues where Visual Studio cannot publish.

[image]